# PHP Imagick Color to Transparent

Tags: php, imagick

I tried to follow http://tech.natemurray.com/2007/12/convert-white-to-transparent.html this tutorial to achieve but my server does not allow to use exec() command to access shell.
How can i implement last piece of code into Imagick library?